# Laravel Nova: Default Select Option From BelongsTo Field

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I need to show selected country in the **Belongs To Fields**
is there any method in which i can pass the value and it would be selected by default.

Comment: Please, show what you tried so far and share some code.

Comment: there is only belongsTo Field  BelongsTo::make('countries') i need to select default value

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/58#issuecomment-419754713) on Github, I tried the following in one of my `BelongsTo` relationship,

```
BelongsTo::make('countries')
    ->withMeta([
        'belongsToId' => 1 // default value for the select
    ]);
```

.. and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

You want to make sure that the value will be set correctly when editing so use the following code:

```
BelongsTo::make('countries')
    ->withMeta([
        'belongsToId' => $this->countries_id ?? 1 // default value for the select
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this issue on Github](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/58#issuecomment-457942889), I tried the following in one of my BelongsTo relationship and it worked.

```
BelongsTo::make('Father', 'parent', UserPageModal::class)
    ->nullable()
    ->filled(function(NovaRequest $request, Model $model) {
        if(is_null($model->parent_id)) {
            $model->parent_id = 0;
        }
    })
```